# Should I install pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py2.7.msi or pygame-1.9.1.win32-py2.7.msi

Tags: version, pygame

I think that pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py2.7.msi is an alpha version, and I don't know that a newbie like myself should mess with that.  Is it more stable than pygame-1.9.1.win32-py2.7.msi, or less?

Why is one twice the size of the other?

Thanks!
PG

Comment: This question seems like a matter of opinion. This is really your call. The reason one is twice as big as the other is either because the installer is less compressed, or because there are just more features in the newer version. Either way, they don't really say anything about performance.

Answer (score 0):

Download pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py2.7.msi. It is the newest version, so it will be better.